# Performing health check of BizTalk without impacting the services

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010, health-monitoring

We have BizTalk servers and lots of services hosted under that. There is load balancer which needs to know the state of BizTalk server. The load balancer performs the ping operation every 5 seconds.

Since the server is requesting BizTalk every 5 seconds it's likely that load will be high on services. which i want to avoid.

I have a thought of creating an echo service and host it in BizTalk so that the load on actual services will be avoided.

But I am unaware that they are any other ways we can perform the health check. Any suggestions and recommendations highly appreciated.

Comment: Which state do you actually need from BizTalk? Is it the state of the host instance(s) or something related to business logic?
Can't you use performance counters for this?

Comment: knowing the state of host instances will be enough i guess. if possible How can i use performance counter, and get the state of hostinstances in very less amount of time? and getting the state of one host instance does it make sure that others are alive?

Comment: it's not viable anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some unclear statements and unproven assumptions in the question. Thus an answer in a general way:

Load balancing in BizTalk has two aspects: network and hosts. Load balancing method depends on the host type: in-process vs. isolated.

[BizTalk Server Monitoring Management Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14897) has capabilities to monitor health of the BizTalk artifacts.

Generally, network load balancer should not pose a problem for the performance as it only polls once per server (not each BizTalk host).

Comment: Great. I added load balancer consideration to the answer.